# Need IF,Vlookup or =INT(MAX whatever can workout number of pleats i need for drops

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need IF,Vlookup or =INT(MAX whatever can workout number of pleats i will need for what ever measurements i type in for excel so if I type window drop e.g 100 window drop will be the number in between 95 and 125 see chart below the amount of pleats this need is 5 or if I type 150 it should show 6 pleats i will need for this drop see below on this chart 95 is drop and 5 is pleats and 125 is drop 6 is pleats etc i hope some body can help. Thanks for your time to read my post. Window Drop: Pleats needed:

95 5 125 6 156 7 186 8 217 9 247 10 278 11 308 12 339 13 369 14 400 15 430 16 461 17 491 18 522 19 552 20 583 21 613 22 644 23 674 24 705 25 735 26 766 27 796 28 827 29 857 30 888 31 918 32 949 33 979 34 1010 35 1040 36 1071 37 1101 38 1132 39 1162 40 1193 41 1223 42 1254 43 1284 44 1315 45 1345 46 1376 47 1406 48 1437 49 1468 50 1499 51 1539 52 1560 53 1590 54 1621 55 1651 56 1682 57 1712 58 1743 59 1773 60 1804 61 1834 62 1865 63 1895 64 1926 65 1956 66 1987 67 2017 68 2048 69 2078 70 2109 71 2139 72 2170 73 2200 74 2231 75 2261 76 2292 77 2322 78 2353 79 2383 80 2414 81 2444 82 2475 83 2505 84 2536 85 2566 86 2597 87 2627 88 2658 89 2688 90 2719 91 2749 92 2780 93 2810 94 2841 95 2871 96 2902 97 2932 98 2963 99 2993 100 3024 101 3054 102 3085 103 3115 104 3146 105 3176 106 3207 107 3237 108 3268 109 3298 110 3329 111 3359 112 3390 113 3420 114 3451 115 3481 116 3512 117

Comment: Could you show how this table of numbers is formatted... Looks random at the moment... But once I see how it goes together, vlookup or index with match may work.

Comment: =IF(C13<125,"5",IF(C13<156,"6",IF(C13<186,"7",IF(C13<217,"8",IF(C13<247,"9",IF(C13<278,"10",IF(C13<308,"11",IF(C13<339,"12",))

Comment: I hope this help i can't add this much nesting so i'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, worried about the numbers in your table, as some are 30 different, others 31...
Cell C2 contains the function used in cell B2..

Anyway, this will work:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,A4:B10,2,1)
```

Edit, Jeeped is correct, need a value close to the value typed in so 1 not 0

Extend the table as far as...
[image]

This can also be done with index & match, especially when the data is separated as long as it has the same length, or when the index column (the one that you look in, not the one with the result) is to the right of the result column. See:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula, you will not be requiring the table with this formula

```
=IF( A1 >= 61*INT((A1-95)/61)+125, 2*INT((A1-125)/61)+6, 2*INT((A1-95)/61)+5)
```

It is assuming that the value you want to enter is present in A1

I figured it out that your table is following the below equations

[image]

The above excel formula is the reverse of the above equations.

Comment: If it is ok for you kindly accept the answer as accepted

Comment: accepted its working and thank you all for sorting this out for me very quickly. I wish i could do some thing for you guys in return 

Comment: I think you have missed it; according to the docs "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in" https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers